# List of .NET classes/methods which are not supported by CoreCLR, Portable, Universal Apps?

Tags: .net, mono, cross-platform, .net-framework-version, coreclr

I really don't understand the last trend that everyone tries to reinvent the wheel or make its own .NET framework profile instead of just making things throw `NotSupportedException`. There are MS .NET, Portable, WP, Silverlight, Universal Apps and Unity3D - all different frameworks.

I know Unity3D has its "Mono Compatibility" page (which really needs to be updated). Also Mono has http://go-mono.com/status/ page.

Is such information available on CoreCLR, Portable and UniversalApps? Where can I find it?

I know that I'm supposed to use the new `GetTypeInfo` reflection in WinRT but where is the full list?

Also if you know any official publications which describe why they introduce so many frameworks I would like to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the .NET part is officially covered here,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/12/04/introducing-net-core.aspx

Mono has its own page because it does not implement many of the full .NET Framework profile.

Unity has its own because it is stuck on Mono 2, while we see Mono 4.2 is coming.